# json_normalize with multiple record paths

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalize

I'm using the example given in the `json_normalize` documentation given here [pandas.json_normalize — pandas 1.0.3 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), I can't unfortunately paste my actual JSON but this example works. Pasted from the documentation:

```
data = [{'state': 'Florida',
     'shortname': 'FL',
     'info': {'governor': 'Rick Scott'},
     'counties': [{'name': 'Dade', 'population': 12345},
                  {'name': 'Broward', 'population': 40000},
                  {'name': 'Palm Beach', 'population': 60000}]},
    {'state': 'Ohio',
     'shortname': 'OH',
     'info': {'governor': 'John Kasich'},
     'counties': [{'name': 'Summit', 'population': 1234},
                  {'name': 'Cuyahoga', 'population': 1337}]}]
result = json_normalize(data, 'counties', ['state', 'shortname',
                                           ['info', 'governor']])
result


         name  population    state shortname info.governor
0        Dade       12345   Florida    FL    Rick Scott
1     Broward       40000   Florida    FL    Rick Scott
2  Palm Beach       60000   Florida    FL    Rick Scott
3      Summit        1234   Ohio       OH    John Kasich
4    Cuyahoga        1337   Ohio       OH    John Kasich
```

What if the JSON was the one below instead where `info` is an array instead of a dict:

```
data = [{'state': 'Florida',
     'shortname': 'FL',
     'info': [{'governor': 'Rick Scott'}, 
              {'governor': 'Rick Scott 2'}],
     'counties': [{'name': 'Dade', 'population': 12345},
                  {'name': 'Broward', 'population': 40000},
                  {'name': 'Palm Beach', 'population': 60000}]},
    {'state': 'Ohio',
     'shortname': 'OH',
     'info': [{'governor': 'John Kasich'}, 
              {'governor': 'John Kasich 2'}],
     'counties': [{'name': 'Summit', 'population': 1234},
                  {'name': 'Cuyahoga', 'population': 1337}]}]
```

How would you get the following output using `json_normalize`:

```
         name  population    state shortname info.governor
0        Dade       12345   Florida    FL    Rick Scott
1        Dade       12345   Florida    FL    Rick Scott 2
2     Broward       40000   Florida    FL    Rick Scott
3     Broward       40000   Florida    FL    Rick Scott 2
4  Palm Beach       60000   Florida    FL    Rick Scott
5  Palm Beach       60000   Florida    FL    Rick Scott 2
6      Summit        1234   Ohio       OH    John Kasich
7      Summit        1234   Ohio       OH    John Kasich 2    
8    Cuyahoga        1337   Ohio       OH    John Kasich
9    Cuyahoga        1337   Ohio       OH    John Kasich 2
```

Or if there is another way to do it, please do let me know.

Comment: What us the issue, exactly? Do you know if this is possible using `json_nomalize()` ?

Comment: That’s what I want to know. If this is possible using `json_normalize`.

Answer (score 6):

`json_normalize` is designed for convenience rather than flexibility. It can't handle all forms of JSON out there (and JSON is just too flexible to write a universal parser for).

How about calling `json_normalize` twice and then merge. This assumes each state only appear once in your JSON:

```
counties = json_normalize(data, 'counties', ['state', 'shortname'])
governors = json_normalize(data, 'info', ['state'])

result = counties.merge(governors, on='state')
```

Comment: Yes merge is a good way to do it, it works with this JSON since state is unique but not in my original JSON where there is no unique identifier per record. But I do agree with your statement on `json_normalize` being more of a convenience, doesn't always work.