# how to unnest a list of json objects in dataframe column

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

What are the possible ways to unnest a list of nested json objects inside a dataframe column and join again with the same dataframe.

e.g.:

```py
data = {
 'tax_info': [
  '[]',
  "[{'price': '1.26', 'rate': 0.06, 'title': 'Idaho State Tax', 'price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': '1.26', 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': '1.26', 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'channel_liable': False}]",
  "[{'price': '1.98', 'rate': 0.0625, 'title': 'Illinois State Tax', 'price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': '1.98', 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': '1.98', 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'channel_liable': False}, {'price': '0.39', 'rate': 0.0125, 'title': 'Chicago City Tax', 'price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': '0.39', 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': '0.39', 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'channel_liable': False}, {'price': '0.87', 'rate': 0.0275, 'title': 'Cook County Tax', 'price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': '0.87', 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': '0.87', 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'channel_liable': False}]"
 ]
}
```

[sample df column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY7Tc.png)

Comment: Please edit your post to include the sample data, rather than posting a screenshot. Please also include the expected output in your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if pandas has anything for parsing stringified data like this, and [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) would not work since that's not valid JSON, but you could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) as below:

```py
# import ast
data = {'tax_info': [[], [{'price': '1.26', 'rate': 0.06, 'title': 'Idaho State Tax', 'price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': '1.26', 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': '1.26', 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'channel_liable': False}], [{'price': '1.98', 'rate': 0.0625, 'title': 'Illinois State Tax', 'price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': '1.98', 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': '1.98', 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'channel_liable': False}, {'price': '0.39', 'rate': 0.0125, 'title': 'Chicago City Tax', 'price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': '0.39', 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': '0.39', 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'channel_liable': False}, {'price': '0.87', 'rate': 0.0275, 'title': 'Cook County Tax', 'price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': '0.87', 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': '0.87', 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'channel_liable': False}]]}

data['tax_info'] = [ast.literal_eval(s) for s in data['tax_info']] 
df = pd.json_normalize(data, ['tax_info', []])

# in one statement, and without altering data:
# pd.json_normalize({**data, 'tax_info': [ast.literal_eval(s) for s in data['tax_info']]}, ['tax_info', []])
```

[image: df]

Comment: Yes it is helpful, thanks. But what is the optimal solution to deal with this issue if you have more nested list of dicts in the data. is it to everytime create a new df and go one level deeper?

Comment: The issue with multiple nested lists is that pandas doesn't know how you want them aligned with each other. So, I think you'll have to loop through the nested columns and make a list of DataFrames, and then [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them along the x-axis [if you  have the same length list for all list-cells in any row (i.e, row 1 only has empty lists, row 2 only has lists of length 3, etc)], or merge them [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61197935/6146136)

Comment: (I usually flatten my data before converting to a DataFrame, but more because I feel like I have more control that way than for efficiency)